# DateInput - Enter a valid date

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form field that I want to have as a calendar widget that defaults to the current date. I had it so it was showing the date in d/m/y format but when I'd submit it would say `Enter a valid date`

**forms.py**

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    published = forms.DateField()
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'published','featured_image', 'post',)
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'blog-title-field', 'placeholder': 'Title'}),
            'published': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), attrs={"type": 'date'}),
            'post': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'blog-post-field', 'placeholder': 'Write something..'}),
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published = models.DateField()
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d')
    post = models.TextField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**create-blog.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container text-center">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.title}}
        {{form.post}}
        {{form.featured_image}}
        {{form.published}}
        {{form.errors}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see carefully, your DateInput format is as `format=('%d-%m-%Y')` while your question states that your format for date is in d/m/y. Try with the hyphen instead of the slash, or vice versa and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you `forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")})` worked